# Change number format in hierarchical list

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

I would like to change number format between different levels in a hierarchical list.

So far I have

- I. Title 1
- **I**.1 Title 2
- **I**.1.1 Title 3

I would like to have

- I. Title 1
- **1**.1 Title 2
- **1**.1.1 Title 3

When I click to change number format for level, I cannot set it on a specific level, it applies to the whole hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Ok looks like there is a checkbox "Use legal formatting" (Or equivalent, I'm not using a EN version), that does this job perfectly.